# JavaScript data structure with ordered items and unique properties / keys?

Tags: javascript

I need a data structure where I can control the order of items in a list, and also ensure a property is unique.

Eg for this array I can control the order, but if I add an object with the same id as an existing object it wont error:

```
const stuff = [{ id: 1, name: "James" }, { id: 2, name: "John" }]
```

Here the keys are unique, but I can't (easily) control the order of items:

```
const stuff = {
  1: {
    name: "James"
  },
  2: {
    name: "John"
  }
}
```

I could use an object and add a field for the order and manually sort by this, but im hoping there's a less verbose way?

Comment: use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: do you have an example of colliding data? what should happen instead?

Comment: @NinaScholz "*it wont error*" Based on this, I',m assuming, it should raise an error.

Comment: or use an class with wraps the input or a `proxy` which could be more complicated than an object with a look up list ... but without clear undertanding of the use case ....

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using a simple wrapper function with array.

- Check if ID exists.

  - If yes, raise error
  - In no, add to the list

```js
const stuff = [{ id: 1, name: "James" }, { id: 2, name: "John" }]

const addUser = (id, name, index) => {
  const userExists = stuff.some(({id: oldId}) => oldId === id)
  if (userExists) {
    console.error("Raising Error")
  } else if (index >= 0) {
    stuff.splice(index, 0, {id, name})
  }
  else {
    stuff.push({id, name})
    console.log("User Added")
  }
}

addUser(5, 'foo')
addUser(5, 'Bar')
addUser(6, 'Bar')
addUser(7, 'Test', 3)

console.log(stuff)
```

---

As rightly commented by [@cmgchess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess), Map can be an effective solution.

```js
const stuff = new Map();
stuff.set(1, 'James');
stuff.set(2, 'John')

const addUser = (id, name) => {
  if (stuff.has(id)) {
    console.error("Raising Error")
  } else {
    stuff.set(id, name)
    console.log("User Added")
  }
}

addUser(5, 'foo')
addUser(5, 'Bar')
addUser(6, 'Bar')

console.log([...stuff])
```

Comment: I thought you couldn't easily control the order with Map? Eg if I have 2 items and I want to insert a new item between them, isnt this much easier with arrays than maps?

Comment: @Evanss you can also have an array and a set. set has the already inserted ids and check if the set has the id. when adding to array add to set too

Comment: @Evanss I think array would be easier in this usecase. But if you could share your usecases, it would be easy to share our suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To explain things,

> Eg for this array I can control the order, but if I add an object with
> the same id as an existing object it wont error:

It is not supposed to throw an error, an array can have duplicate objects (unlike [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)). However, what you can do is, you can validate before adding objects to the array. You'll have to write a custom function for that.

To answer your question, With ES2015/ES6 you have [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type.

```
const map = new Map([
  ['1', { id: 1, name: "James" }],
  ['2', { id: 2, name: "John" }],
])

console.log(...map.entries())
```

Answer (score 0):

Object, Map or Set can solve unique part, but as I know, you will need some extra structure (like array) to store your items order.Map/Set iterates items in a same order you put them in Map/Set.

If you need more control for order - extra array will help.

For simple Object it will be like:

```
    const stuff = {
      order:[2,1],
      toArray: function(){
        return this.order.map(id=>stuff[id])
      },
      push: function(id,obj){
        if(this[id] === undefined)
        {
          this[id] = obj
          this.order.push(id)
        } else {
          // if you want to replace an existing item
          this[id] = obj
        }
      },
      1: {
        name: "James"
      },
      2: {
        name: "John"
      }
    }
```

Or you can use a simple array of objects + custom functions to add elements in it:

```
const stuff = [{ id: 1, name: "James" }, { id: 2, name: "John" }]
function addUniqueId(arr,obj,f = 'push'){
    const i = arr.findIndex(el=>el.id === obj.id)
    i === -1 ? arr[f](obj) : arr[i] = obj
}

let a = stuff[1] // { id: 2, name: "John" }
addUniqueId(stuff,{ id: 2, name: 123 })
// stuff now is: [{ id: 1, name: "James" }, { id: 2, name: 123 }]
// a now is: { id: 2, name: "John" }
```

Note: if you need to change values for all existing links (like 'a') - don't use

```
arr[i] = obj
```

you will need something like a deep copy but with already existing object as a target:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>arr[i][key] = obj[key])
// a will also be: { id: 2, name: 123 }
```

It will edit the existing object (not replace it like before), but you may have some issues if old and new keys are different - in this case just remove all old keys first:

```
    function addUniqueId(arr,obj,f = 'push'){
      const i = arr.findIndex(el=>el.id === obj.id)
        if (i === -1) 
          arr[f](obj); 
        else {
           Object.keys(arr[i]).forEach(key=>delete arr[i][key]);
           Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>arr[i][key] = obj[key]);
        }
    }
```